# How does swipl manage term memory?

Tags: prolog, webassembly, swi-prolog

I was trying to do some shenanigans with the swipl compiled to wasm, but I am a bit confused about how swipl manages terms memory in such environments. Do I have to use `PL_open_foreign_frame` and `PL_close_foreign_frame` to avoid memory leaks from the calls to the `PL_new_term_ref`, since I am the one calling to the prolog runtime, and not the runtime calling me as a foreign predicate? And if I wanted to store multiple solutions for the predicate for later use, how would I go about doing that? After I call `PL_next_solution`, all of the references are invalidated up until the first time `PL_next_solution` was called. Do I have to use a list, and something like `findall/3` to do that?

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to answer - anyway... nice question, hope you will tell us about your findings and outcome... FWIW, when I was coding the Qt console, Jan pointed me to fast serialization of terms as the only reliable interface among threads. Guess you are in a similar position...